# How to open the advanced search for Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

From the Inbox view, the simple search can be accessed by clicking in the "Search current mailbox" field or by pressing Ctrl+E. I have seen people use a more advanced version of this search that has several fields (such as from, title, text body...). How do I open or access this more advanced search? (see picture below: basically what it is supposed to look like). This is *not* the "Advanced Find" (Ctrl+Shift+F), which is in a new window – this one is in the main window, just like the Ctrl+E search.

[image: Advanced search]

This is probably a 2 sec Google search but I cannot find the correct terms to describe what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you click in the search bar, the search tab is now selected.

At the end of the search section is a "+more" command, clicking that will bring up a list of categories to add to the search.[image]